# IIS Process starts but ASP.NET core does not unless I request page

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, iis, .net-core, windows-server-2016

I have an issue with an ASP.NET Core 3.1 web app. I need this app to start automatically when it crashes or server restarts without waiting for the next user to login so that it starts.
For this I set the Application Pool **Start Mode** to **AlwaysRunning**, **Idle Time-out** setting to **0**, **Regular Time Interval** to **0** and on the web site have set the **Preload Enabled** to **True**.
That works on all servers that we have except for one server that I can see that the w3wp process starts but not the asp.net core app if I restart the Application Pool or restart the machine. I don't see any errors in the event viewer.

What might be causing this or how can I troubleshoot it further?

Comment: Are all servers running exactly the same version of Windows? Maybe one of them is on an older version where the feature ether isn't present, is misconfigured, or has a bug compared to the others?

Comment: All servers running the same version of windows.

Comment: Use in-process hosting mode please.

Answer (score 1):

I have same issue on Windows 10 and IIS version is 10. This solution works for me:

On Windows 7 or later desktop systems when using IIS locally:
**Navigate to Control Panel** > **Programs** > **Programs and Features** > **Turn Windows features on or off** (left side of the screen).
**Open Internet Information Services** > **World Wide Web Services** > **Application Development Features**.
Select the checkbox for **Application Initialization**.

Using web.config, add the  element with doAppInitAfterRestart set to true to the <system.webServer> elements in the app's web.config file add this section

```
 <system.webServer>
      <applicationInitialization doAppInitAfterRestart="true" />
 </system.webServer>
```

After that you must change applicationHost.config two section change C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config\applicationHost.config

First section below:

```
<site name="yoursitename" id="3" serverAutoStart="true">
    <application path="/" applicationPool="yoursitename" preloadEnabled="true" serviceAutoStartEnabled="true" serviceAutoStartProvider="ApplicationPreload">
        <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="C:\websites\yoursitename" />
    </application>
    <bindings>
        <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:8011:" />
    </bindings>
</site>
```

Second section below:

```
<add name="yoursitename" autoStart="true" startMode="AlwaysRunning">
    <processModel idleTimeout="00:00:00" />
       <recycling>
        <periodicRestart time="00:00:00" />
    </recycling>
</add>
```

*PS: if you want to stop the project completely you must stop in application pool.*

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/advanced?view=aspnetcore-6.0#application-initialization-module